# Counting down from an input value in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to assign the value of input `aa` to the signal `t` in the code below. It compiles successfully, but there is a warning:

WARNING[9]: C:/Modeltech_5.7f/examples/hassan1.vhd(14): (vcom-1013) **Initial value of "t" depends on value of signal "aa".**

Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all; 
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all ;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 
entity counter is
port(clk :in std_logic;
 reset : in std_logic;
 aa: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 check : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end counter;     

architecture imp of counter is 
signal i:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000"; 
signal t:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=aa;
begin
 process(clk)
  begin
  if rising_edge(clk) and (t>0) then
      t<=t-1;
      i<=i+1;
  end if;
 end process;
check<=i;
end  imp;
```

What should I be doing in order to decrement the input 'aa' in the process? The program is meant to decrement the value at input `aa` to 0.

Comment: So what is the actual question you are asking?

Comment: how can i remove this warning

Comment: I think that is probably the wrong question, but the answer to it is; always make sure your signal initialisers are constants.

Comment: then what should i be doing in order to decrement the input 'aa' in the process? as the program is meant to decrement the value at input to 0.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to implement a down-counter with a load input. In such a counter, when `load_enable = '1'` you should register the load input value (`aa` in your case) into an internal signal. When `load_enable = '0'`, you would decrement this count value. Here is a code example that does that:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity down_counter is
  port (
    clock: in std_logic;
    reset: in std_logic;
    load_enable: in std_logic;
    load_data: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    output: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
  );
end;

architecture rtl of down_counter is
    signal count: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    process (clock, reset) begin
        if reset then
            count <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if load_enable then
                count <= load_data;
            else
                count <= count - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    output <= count;
end;
```

For the record, the code above can be improved, but I didn't want to throw too much stuff at once. It is probably a good idea to use an integer instead of std_logic_vector for your count signal. Also you should check if the count proceeds as you expected, since the example uses the `numeric_std_unsigned` package. I'd recommend that you change it to `numeric_std` once you understand the code completely.

Comment: can we use load_enable as a signal instead of input?because i want to make it zero after data is loaded.

Comment: How to I change this code into a decade counter?